# How do you demo a spike?

Tags: scrum, agile, safe

Do spikes need to be demoed or you kind of just describe the knowledge gathered from the spike.

During a Team Demo in safe.
http://v4.scaledagileframework.com/team-demo/

Looks like the team could. But how do they do that. Technically the software solution did not change.

Comment: In what context? What meeting? Demoed to whom?

Comment: In agile, at the end of every sprint there is a demo to the stakeholders.

Comment: Related: https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/22220/4271

Comment: [The Scrum Guide](http://scrumguides.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Scrum, at a Sprint Review, "you inspect the increment and adapt the Product Backlog". Spikes (which aren't even defined in [the Scrum Guide](http://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html)) are a method to capture things that your team needs to do in order to investigate, learn, and be able to deliver a Product Backlog Item in the current or future Sprint. There's no stakeholder value being delivered by completing a Spike.

Typically, there is nothing to demonstrate in a Spike. You haven't done anything to the project that you are working on. If anything, you may have completed a prototype or mockup. But you wouldn't want to demonstrate that at a Sprint Review for fear of giving the impression that there has been more work done on the design and development work for the Product Backlog Items.

Any completed Spikes are useful in the Sprint Review, however. Part of the purpose of the Sprint Review is to revise the Product Backlog. Based on the Spike, you have learned information about one or more other stories which may have led to additional detail being added, stories being decomposed.

So, no. You do not include Spikes when reviewing the work that you have accomplished in the Sprint. You may want to mention that you have done certain Spikes to better understand particular work, but that's about it.

---

Note: This answer was originally written against [Revision 1 of the question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/revisions/22243/1). This revision only contained tags referencing [scrum](/questions/tagged/scrum) and [agile](/questions/tagged/agile). The information regarding SAFe was added in Revision 2. This answer is based on my experience with Scrum and Disciplined Agile Delivery and not SAFe. [SAFe does have guidance on Spikes that, to some extent, disagrees with this answer](http://www.scaledagileframework.com/spikes/).

Comment: @otc Sorry about that. I added some stuff - I was distracted when writing the answer and pressed submit before I was totally done.

Comment: Cool, looking at Safe looks like they demo the spikes 
http://v4.scaledagileframework.com/team-demo/
But getting a mixed message accross the internet.

Comment: @otc You tagged your question with [tag:scrum] and did not mention SAFe. I can't speak to SAFe. But, like I said, Spikes are not a traditional part of Scrum (not mentioned in the Scrum Guide), but based on how people tend to use them (and how I've used them), I've given a good practice based on the information that is available in the Scrum Guide. If you want an answer in the context of SAFe, you need to specify that.

Comment: Cool thanx updating.

Comment: Sry did not know if it mattered, thank you for the details. they look good.

Comment: Both [SAFe](http://v4.scaledagileframework.com/team-demo/) and [Scrum](http://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#events-review) require that work from the increment be demoed. Spikes count as work. I won't downvote at this time because I understand where you're coming from, but if you can't find a way to demonstrate the result or information gleaned from a spike then you're probably thinking about demoes incorrectly. There was even a recent question elsewhere about how to demo non-visual things.

Comment: @CodeGnome Scrum does not require that the work from the increment be demoed. It says that the review is used to "inspect the Increment". The Increment is "the sum of all the Product Backlog items completed". Although I prefer to put Spikes on the Product Backlog for tracking and planning purposes, [common advice is to not put it on the Product Backlog](https://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/blog/spikes) and to [not estimate Spikes (only timebox them)](https://www.leadingagile.com/2014/04/dont-estimate-spikes/). Since it doesn't represent anything to be delivered, there's no need to review it.

Comment: @CodeGnome However, my last sentence is also important: "You may want to mention that you have done certain Spikes to better understand particular work, but that's about it." You can "demo" or "review" a spike by doing two things. First, having better groomed Product Backlog Items that the Spike was meant to address. Second, by being able to talk about the things that you learned and how you learned them.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Actually, Scrum is quite clear that work is to be demoed. I provided a link above, which says "The Development Team demonstrates the work that it has “Done” and answers questions about the Increment[.]" The only possible debate is about whether you consider spikes to be "work" or wish it into the cornfield as an invisible drag on productivity.

Comment: @CodeGnome Spikes do not add value to the end users or customers. They are of benefit only to the Development Team. A team should not spend a lot of time in a Review on a Spike.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I fundamentally disagree that learning, information, or feedback are of value only to the development team, and therefore I agree with the framework designers that spikes ought to be treated like any other visible aspect of the increment. However, reasonable practitioners can and do disagree; I'm happy to leave it there so long as people new to the thread don't walk away with the notion that Scrum and SAFe don't address the topic of spikes in any way, and can form their own conclusions from the source material.

Comment: @CodeGnome You won't find the word "Spike" anywhere in the Scrum Guide, so Scrum is silent on the issue. I'm only somewhat familiar with SAFe, but it does appear that the SAFe framework (unlike Scrum) does provide more specific guidance for Spike, including that you not only put them on the backlog and estimate them, but also demonstrate them. The guidance in SAFe is not what I've found to be good practice. Also note that this question, originally and when this answer was written, contained no references to SAFe and this answer is built on my experience with Scrum - I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with the other answer given. The Scrum Guide simply says about the Sprint Review: "During the Sprint Review, the Scrum Team and stakeholders collaborate about what was done in the Sprint." The goal of this event is to collaborate between the team and the stakeholders or users in order to get feedback and determine the next step forward.

While some spikes may not be appropriate to share because they might make no sense to the stakeholders, many are. Here are two examples I've experienced where it was clearly valuable to review spikes:

- The team was evaluating two options for CMS plugins to support a feature. As a spike, they created two new throw-away screens that implemented the basic functionality of the plug-ins. They were able to share with stakeholders their recommendation based on ease of implementation and the stakeholders gave feedback on which prototype gave them the look and feel they prefered.
- A team was working with a new API. We created a little script that connected to the API pulled some data. We reviewed this with stakeholders in order to validate that the information we were able to retrieve from the API was the correct information that they needed for their purposes.

Part of this also comes when planning the spikes. Often time there are ways to approach the problem that offer no opportunity for stakeholder feedback and ways that offer a lot of opportunity. I personally always favor the 2nd option if the effort is similar.

Answer (score 1):

A spike is an experiment, so the expectations vs the results should be demonstrated, if not via a demo, via a:

- a benchmark comparison
- a competitive analysis chart
- a design document
- a flow diagram
- a screencast
- a burnup chart
- a QA/QE test plan

> The output of a spike is demonstrable, both to the team and to any other stakeholders. This brings visibility to the research and architectural efforts and also helps build collective ownership and shared responsibility for the key decisions that are being taken.

**References**

- [Guidance – Spikes – Scaled Agile Framework](http://www.scaledagileframework.com/spikes/)
- [How to manage QA complexity: Use spikes and a feature test review](https://techbeacon.com/how-clear-qa-complexity-use-spikes-feature-test-review)